# Probability of Seeing a Car in 10 Minutes & 30 Minutes

Tags: mathematics, calculation-puzzle

On a deserted road, the probability of observing a car during a thirty-minute period is 95%. 
What is the chance of observing a car in a ten-minute period?

Hint:
To clarify the question we are saying the probability of seeing any other cars in 30 minutes is 95% or more clearly, and more usefully, the probability of not seeing any other cars is 5%.

Comment: btw how you put spoiler box?

Comment: You can use >!  to hide spoilers

Comment: I believe this question is not on-topic here because it is a math problem, not a math puzzle, [as per meta discussion](http://meta.puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/2783/4551). It should instead go on math.SE.

Comment: I understand why you may see it as a just a math problem, for me because I not enter in the probabality field frequently, the solution was nice. I only could solve this problem when I realize the similitud to solve the problem `probabilty of have 3 head coin toss in a row` that was my eureka moment for the day.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The answer is:

> 100% -  5%^(1/3) (cube root of 5%), which is about 63%

Why?

> Because the probability of not seeing a car in thirty minutes is equal to the probability of not seeing a car for ten minutes to the third power. That is, `not seeing a car for ten minutes` three times in a row is like `not seeing a car for thirty minutes`

Or, with a formula:

> If $P_{not30}$ is the probability of not seeing a car for 30 minutes and $P_{not10}$ is the probability of not seeing a car for ten minutes, $P_{not30}$= $P_{not10}^ 3 \Rightarrow$ $P_{not10} = \sqrt[3]{P_{not30}}$

Comment: just showing powers,cubes is not useful explain with numbers :)

Comment: @user232783 What do you mean? This: `1 - cube_root(0.05) ~= 1 - 0.3684031498640387 = 0.6315968501359612 ~= 0.63 = 63%`?